# Is it necessary to have attributes in model for every field in database table?

Tags: backbone.js

I have a table(tbl_brand) with five fields and i want to make model and collection for that table. Is it necessary to have all field
s attributes in model?

Comment: nope, only fields you are going to operate with

Comment: why not try & find it and let us know if you get stuck. Or is the question about best approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you need to have attributes in model for every field in database table. Otherwise it wont work.